# mod_rewrite not forwarding to new URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've read almost everywhere, I disabled MultiViews, a2enmods rewrite, and almost everything else I can find.

My .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^PHP/ig/profile.php?user=([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ /PHP/ig/profile/$1 [L]
```

My site config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@espionage.pw
    DocumentRoot /var/www/espionage.pw/public_html
    ServerName espionage.pw
    ServerAlias www.espionage.pw
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/espionage.pw/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

My .htaccess file is in /var/www/espionage.pw/
And I can confirm that it IS being read, as when I enter random characters, there is an error when trying to connect to my website.

I am just at a loss for what to do.  Please suggest anything and everything that could possibly help.  I have been working all day on this and I am starting to get angry...

Thanks for any help.

EDIT:
I also have a single error in error.log
[Fri Aug 22 19:00:35.168341 2014] [negotiation:error] [pid 20230] [client myip:62633] AH00687: Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: /var/www/espionage.pw/public_html/PHP/ig/profile (None could be negotiated).

I removed MultiViews, so this should have been resolved.

I have also tried:

```
RewriteRule ^/PHP/ig/profile.php$ /PHP/index.php [L]
```

which did not rewrite /PHP/ig/profile.php to /PHP/index.php

Comment: What is the actual URL that gets called by the browser, that you want to rewrite?

Comment: I am trying to call http://espionage.pw/PHP/ig/profile.php?user=blah and have it forward to http://espionage.pw/PHP/ig/profile/blah

Comment: RewriteRule only looks at the path component of the URL, it does not take the query string into account. If you want to match on the query string, you have to use a RewriteCond to do that. (And if by “forwarding” you mean an actual external redirect, you will have to add the `R` flag as well, otherwise the request will only be rewritten internally.)

Comment: I will try this, and no, I dont mean a redirect, I just didnt know what to call it.

Comment: Then I don’t understand why you would want to rewrite the request in that “direction” – _normally_ people want to do this the other way around, have the “nice” URL `/PHP/ig/profile/blah` show up in the browser, and rewrite it internally to `/PHP/ig/profile.php?user=blah` so that the script gets the value passed as parameter that it can work with …

Comment: I tried to do this RewriteRule ^/PHP/ig/profile.php$ /PHP/index [L]
to see if it would rewrite to /PHP/ig/profile.php, and that still did not work...

Comment: I also tried RewriteRule ^/PHP/ig/profile/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ /PHP/ig/profile.php?user=$1 [L]
To see if I could get /PHP/ig/profile/blah to rewrite to /PHP/ig/profile.php?user=blah, and it still failed to work.

Comment: When used in .htaccess context, the path that the pattern is applied to never starts with a slash, so `^/…` will never match.

Comment: I have tried with and without the /, neither seemed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your document root is:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/espionage.pw/public_html
```

And you state that your `.htaccess` file is located in the folder:

```
/var/www/espionage.pw
```

Apache will never serve files from `/var/www/espionage.pw` as it is not part of the document root so your `.htaccess` file will not be read or used at all.

You need to place your `.htaccess` file in the `/var/www/espionage.pw/public_html` folder or a folder inside that folder if you want to limit its use to a sub-folder.

Comment: You dont know how much time I have wasted looking at tutorials and trying to figure this out.  Thank you so much.

Comment: Nice catch, I missed that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure, since the full .htaccess is not posted...did you place

```
RewriteEngine On
```

before the rule?